# Why does my GTK CSS button color only work when my application is not selected?

Tags: c, ubuntu-18.04, gtk3

I'm trying to change button colors using CSS the issue is that is only works when I select an other application. When I select my application all the CSS changes disappears. I cant find a solution to this, any help would be appretiated. 
I've attached my simplified code and results.
Thanks

`

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

gtk_init(&argc,&argv);
GtkWidget* window;
GtkWidget *button_quit;
GtkWidget *grid;


window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

grid = gtk_grid_new ();
gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), grid);

// styling background color to black

   static const char *css =
   "#button_quit{"
   "background-color: darkgoldenrod;"
   "color: black;"
   "font-family: darkseagreen;"
   "font-style: normal;"
   "font-weight: bold;"
   "font-size: 30px;"
   "border-radius: 5px;"
   "}";


GtkCssProvider* provider = gtk_css_provider_new();
GdkDisplay* display = gdk_display_get_default();
GdkScreen* screen = gdk_display_get_default_screen(display);
gtk_css_provider_load_from_data(GTK_CSS_PROVIDER(provider),css,-1, NULL);
gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen(screen,
                                                          GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(provider),
                                                          GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);
g_object_unref(provider);


//create quit button
button_quit = gtk_button_new_with_label("Quit");
gtk_widget_set_name(button_quit, "button_quit");
g_object_set (button_quit, "margin", 10, NULL);
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button_quit), "clicked",
     G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), G_OBJECT(window));


gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), button_quit, 0, 0, 1, 1);

gtk_widget_show_all(window);
gtk_main();

return 0;
}
```

`

Pictures:

[My app is not selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9bcZ.png)

[My app is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COrWK.png)

Comment: You can add your image inline, please follow instructions here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344853/3519504

Comment: i am using ubuntu 20 and its working fine for me..maybe this issue is related to you window manager or the theme you are using now.. try using the selector focus "button:focus"  and GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION this priority should be enough.

Comment: Thanks I tried focus with no sucess. After more digging into this I concluded that my CSS styles only apply to a backdrop state. not sure how to fix this. I suspect is has to do with GTK_BACKDROP_STYLING. and GTK 3.22

Answer (score 0):

My css style were loading as a backdrop state?. I inserted a new general button style before my new definitions and it resolve the problems. Not sure why this resolved it but it did.

```
button {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: @bg_color;
}
```